# How do I implement this particular form pattern in database?

Tags: mysql, database

I need this particular form to be implemented, how should I store the entered data into the database?

[image]

Comment: So there's never more than 1 'availability' per day?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use two columns 
1) Int (null) to save 24 hours checked or not 
2) Varchar: e.g. Monday : 12 to 7, Tuesday : 2 to 3, and so on

While fetching parse the result using ',' then each day using ':' and 'to'

Alternatively you can use 1 column but that will involve more parsing 
1) varchar: Monday : 11 am to 2 pm, Tuesday : 10am to 2pm (for 24 unchecked) 
or 
1) varchar : Monday : 11 to 14, Tuesday : 10 to 14 and so on 
Here you can check if am/pm is present and work accordingly

Comment: Thanx alot man btw whats with all the downvotes for my question ?

Comment: @Glorious15 Ask question with showing your tries, errors you got and like that. not just directly asking problem.
Accept answer if it is what you expect

Comment: you can have that by using e.g. Monday : 2am to 10am , 3pm to 5pm ; Tuesday : 10am to 11 am , 2pm to 5pm and so on (notice comma and semicolon)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON format to store data into the database. JSON Query will help to find entity value as well.